# Synonyms: [anacrusis], [pickup-measure], [pickup-bar]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I don't have the required score in any of these tags to suggest any tag synonyms, but all three seem to be expressing the exact same idea. What do you guys think?

Comment: These are all newly created tags the newest being only a week old. The better question may be do we need these tags.

Comment: I believe one of them would be more than enough

Comment: @Shevliaskovic Are you saying we actually don't need any of them?

Comment: @Richard no. We've had questions tagged with these, so we do. But one is enough, so 3>enough :P

Comment: Some anacruces are longer than one bar, so 'pickup bar' isn't a synonym. And if the anacrucis is, say, one beat, then pickup bar isn't the same. Bar and measure are.

Comment: @Tim But all pickups are also anacruses, correct? So we could have [anacrusis] as one tag and the others as synonyms included in the broader category. To me a question about a pickup measure itself and not about a more general concept of anacrusis is still served perfectly well with an [anacrusis] tag and we don't need the granularity of a separate tag for each possible type and aspect of anacrusis.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - yes, pickup = anacrucis. But the OP said 'pickup bar'. Am I being too picky?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point all of the questions tagged with [pickup-bar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pickup-bar) were retagged with [pickup-measure](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pickup-measure).

And in 2021 [pickup-measure](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pickup-measure) was made a synonym of [anacrusis](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anacrusis).  (As can been seen in the comment to this answer:
[Tag Synonyms Proposals Repository!](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/tag-synonyms-proposals-repository/3769#3769))

So these three tags have all collapsed into one tag.  This post can be marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps all of these terms are too specific to warrant being tags?

Questions relating to these subjects could be tagged `notation`, or `phrasing`, or perhaps `meter`, depending on the specific question.